# How to define multiple styles for one CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing a dark mode on my site, and trying to do it in the cleanest way possible (no boiler plate code).

So I want to make .darkmode class in CSS, define styles with it, and when the user enables darkmode, javascript simply adds the darkmode class to the `<body>`.

How could I do something like this with CSS?

```
.darkmode {
    .content{
        background-color: black;
    }
    input{
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

So my questions is, how can I make CSS change different elements on the page when adding this class to the `<body>`?

Comment: You can't do this syntactic sugar in CSS but you can in Sass or Less. The only way to do it in vanilla CSS would be `.darkmode .content {...}` `.darkmode input {...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you posted would be valid SCSS/LESS. But in plain css you can simply do that by using

```
.darkmode .content { /* CSS */ }
.darkmode input { /* CSS */ }
```

So yes, you always have to specify the `.darkmode` in front of every selector.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a selector, like

```
.mydiv .myanchor
```

You can override/add attributes using

```
body.darkmode .mydiv .myanchor
```

is much more specific and therefore the rules will override the default rules.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that in normal CSS you would have to use the CSS child selector;

```
body.darkmode .content {
  /* Put styles here */
}
body.darkmode input {
  /* Put styles here */
}
```

Basically the logic there says: *"get the `body` element with the class `darkmode` and find it's child `.content`/`input`"*

With CSS selectors, having two element selectors seporated by a space finds all of the second elements inside the first elements; `div p` would find all of the `<p>` tags inside all `<div>` tags.